# How to decide the processing power required based on the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

To train a machine learning model, the computer often needs more processing power. In this case, a powerful CPU is needed, since it is a large data set, it needs more memory, so rather than a CPU, GPU is the solution.

Do we need to decide which processor to use before we proceed? For example, will a 30000 sample data set need this much processing power?

Thanks in advance.

If any part of this question is not clear, please comment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataset (number of samples, number of features) is one variable. Algo/model complexity is another.

For example, linear regression will be much faster as compared to 4 layer neural network (and will require much lesser compute power).

So, before deciding need for compute powers, you can :

1. Try few models with hardware (or AWS instances) you already have
2. Estimate need for better hardware (CPU / GPU) based on the performance and what is the bottleneck

For very large data sets (say 10 TB+), I/O can become the bottleneck.

Comment: Got it, thank u. @ShamitVerma